# Prevent Swift files from being exposed to the Objective-C Generated Interface Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

Is it possible to explicitly declare that a Swift source file isn't included in the Objective-C Generated Interface Header? As an example, let's say I have this Swift class

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
}
```

In my `MyApp-Swift.h` generated header, I see this

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC4MyApp16MyViewController")
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString * _Nullable)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle * _Nullable)nibBundleOrNil OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)coder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

However I would prefer this class isn't exposed to Objective-C. I'm working in a larger app, and our generated `-Swift.h` file is well over 8,000 lines. This ends up making incremental builds painful when something that should only require a recompilation of the Swift code ends up causing a recompilation of the Objective-C code as well simply because this header file changed.

`@nonobjc` sadly does not work. I receive the error `'@nonobjc' attribute cannot be applied to this declaration`.

Comment: Why you market it public then?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I've clarified by removing `public` from the question. In that context, `public` is declaring that it is visible outside of its module. It has no relation to whether or not it should be exposed to Objective-C via the generated header. 

But just in case I did validate that after removing `public` in this specific example, it does still appear in the generated header.

Comment: I think you can't make it @nonobjc if you have one of your method with @objc. This is always true when you create a custom `UIButton` or `UIGesstureRecognizer` and need a method to respond to those actions.